# iOS: Handling Remote (push) Notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to handle all possible cases with remote notifications.
I'm ok when app in foreground - didReceiveRemoteNotification is called.
The problem is when app in background state, and I receive push notification.
Nothing is called.
how to let user know that he has new remote notification when app come back to foreground ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way for you to intercept a push notification is when the user tap the notify in the notification center (or when slide the app icon from the lock screen).

In this case before the app go in foreground the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the app delegate is called. You should use the `NSDictionary` `launchOptions` to determine if the app has been launched from notification center or by tapping the icon (the normal use)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *pushDic = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
    if (pushDic != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Notification");
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Comment: The UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey is actually a defined constant not the string value

Comment: hi , i have a similar scenario but slightly modification required ,but like when i get the push notification ,the app would get active in background and do the task given in ,- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo , but my app would not get active until user taps on the notification . so , how would i get this done while app is in background ? dose anyone know the solution for this ?

Answer (score -3):

Just have a look into the programming guide:

If the action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system launches the application and the application calls its delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the local-notification object (for local notifications).

Comment: The docs say this is the handling if the application is not running in foreground, there is no distinction made between "dead" and background.

Comment: `The user launched the application in response to the arrival of a remote notification. In this case, the dictionary contains the notification payload dictionary described in the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method. (Key: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey)`

Comment: @Tom this is correct, but application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is only called when the app is first launched, this does not solve the issue of when the app is in the background, and then launched from tapping a button in the notification centre.

Answer (score -3):

Of course, if your app is in background, there will be nothing called...

If your app is not launched (not even suspended in background), the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

will contain the notification payload (key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey):

```
NSDictionary *remoteNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

Comment: If it is in the background - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo is called.